# Kusto :How to query daily data to aggregate by Month and generate trends

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Our kusto table has data for the last 12 months of daily data and I am trying to get trends for  last 6 months 1) # of distinct customerId per month
2)# of orders(using orderId field) per customer(customerId) by Month

I tried below for #1 question but its not giving correct results looks like by understanding of bin function is not accurate. Any thoughts on  what function i should be using to get #1 and #2 questions data please?

Note : each day has multiple batches of data like 9am, 12 pm,18 pm ,12pm

```
let data = datatable(customerid:int, processdate:datetime, orderId: string)
    [
        1,"2021-03-03 09:00:00", "a",
        1,"2021-03-03 12:00:00", "b",
        1,"2021-03-03 15:00:00", "c",
        2,"2021-03-04 21:00:00", "d",
        2,"2021-03-04 14:00:00", "e",
        2,"2021-03-04 09:00:00", "f",
        1,"2021-04-03 09:00:00", "g",
        1,"2021-04-03 12:00:00", "h",
        1,"2021-04-03 15:00:00", "j",
        2,"2021-05-04 21:00:00", "k",
        2,"2021-05-04 14:00:00", "l",
        2,"2021-05-04 09:00:00", "m"
        
    ];
data
//|where processdate > ago(180d) commeted out as example data does not data to satisfy this filter
|summarize customercount = dcount(customerid) by bin(processdate,30d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`startofmonth` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction)